# How to segment periods above and below zero for a plot in R

Tags: r

I have created a random walk function which runs for a certain period of time. When I plot the walk, it goes to values which are above and below zero. Im wondering if there is a way for me to find the parts of the graph which are above zero. When I run the function, I get this output :

```
      Time     Steps    Time intervals
[1,]    0        0           34
[2,]   34        2           24
[3,]   58        4           35
[4,]   93        2           29
[5,]  122        0           37
[6,]  159        1           29
[7,]  188        3           35
[8,]  223        0           29
[9,]  252        -1          28
[10,] 280        -4
```

So in this case, the first positive segment is between rows 1 - 5 or between times 0 and 122. The other is between rows 6-8 or between times 159 - 223. This is a small segment of the entire output, so there are a number of positive and negative segments. What I'm struggling with, is code that will count the number of positive segments. In this case the value would be 2, but with the full output there are a lot more. Additionally, I'm wondering if there is a way to directly reference each segment. For instance, if there are 5 positive segments, is there a way for me to directly reference the last positive segment, and say calculate its duration by summing the respective time intervals. I don't really have any idea of how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: *"What I'm struggling with, is code that will count the number of positive segments. In this case the value would be 1..."* maybe make your example take 2 positive segments? So it better reflects your use case. `data.table::releid` on `sign(steps)` is probably the easiest way, or something like that depending on the 0 behavior you want.

Comment: Good point, will do. thanks!